# How to commit just one file in a directory?

Tags: git, github

I've been learning Go and I created a directory as recommended as `C:\Users\A\Desktop\go` and in the go directory I have bin, src and pkg. In src, I have a folder "play" where I put all tutorial and exercises and code. In git bash I cd to `C:\Users\A\Desktop\go` and do `git init` and `git add .` When I do `git status` I get a list of hundreds of files including tutorials, exercises etc. But I just want to commit one file which is `wiki.go` and its related files. How do I do that? I read several tutorials but cannot figure this out. And I am working alone on this code.

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you want to commit just `wiki.go`, or `wiki.go` and all of its "related files".

Comment: wiki.go and all its related files, like templates...

Answer (score 3):

After the `git init`, to just commit just `wiki.go` you would:

```
git add wiki.go
git commit -m 'Add wiki.go.'
```

The `git add .` will add all the files which would make the next `git commit` add them all.

Comment: Why would you do both `git add .` and `git add wiki.go`? The original poster just wants the last one.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong: `A@A-PC /c/users/a/desktop/go (master)
$ git add wiki15.go
fatal: pathspec 'wiki15.go' did not match any files`

Comment: It might be that `wiki15.go` is not in the current directory.  If it is in a directory above just add `<directory_name>/` before `wiki15.go`.

Comment: wiki15.go is in this directory: `/src/play/gowiki/wiki15.go` But that does not work either: `A@A-PC /c/users/a/desktop/go (master)
$ git add /src/play/gowiki/wiki15.go
fatal: Could not switch to 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/src/play/gowiki/': No suc
h file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

To commit only file `my_file`, just do:

```
git commit my_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The original poster states:

> I just want to commit one file which is wiki.go and its related files.

I'm assuming that the `wiki.go` and its related files are under the `src/play` directory, as the original poster states:

> In src, I have a folder "play" where I put all tutorial and exercises and code.

So to add `wiki.go` and related files, just pass the folder path to `git add`:

```
$ git add <directory of wiki.go>
```

You can read more about how to use the [`git add` command at the official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html).

Comment: I am having no luck with this: `A@A-PC /c/users/a/desktop/go (master)
$ git add /c/users/a/desktop/go/src/play/gowiki/wiki15.go
fatal: Path 'src/play/gowiki/wiki15.go' is in submodule 'src/play/gowiki'

A@A-PC /c/users/a/desktop/go (master)
$ git add /src/play/gowiki/wiki15.go
fatal: Could not switch to 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/src/play/gowiki/': No suc
h file or directory`

Comment: It sounds like you managed to initialize a Git submodule in the `src/play/gowiki` folder. Please add the exact steps you used to create your Git repository (and submodules?) to your question.

Comment: I'll try Mercurial, I don't think git is for me. I may close this question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Zeynel very well, but if in the future you decide to give Git another try, I highly recommend the [free online book Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book), it taught me 85% of what I know about how to use Git effectively. I recommend chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5.